# Dripping Content for every User

Tags: entities, nodes, users

a customer asked me about content dripping in drupal. he said that it works in wordpress, but he need that in drupal.

so first of all what is content dripping? He need its for his own customers, who pay for a abo of its site content. So the abo runs for e.g. 10 weeks and the user gets 10 nodes with content on them, e.g.  chapters of a book.

So what he needs now is that the content "dripps" to the user, so the user gets every week a new chapter.

My first intention was to use rules, trigger and node_access to build up a custom set of rules to give the user the permissions once a week.

Then i searched around a lot and found a php script what does excactly that. It gets a list of all members, looks for the date of the abo and checks against a cck field in the node, and if the date is higher than the week of the abo + abo registration date, the content gets accessible.

but it would be much easier and better if i had a module...

So is there any module that does excatly that? As far as i know is content dripping a well known method in online marketing, so maybe there is something?

Comment: "dripping content" can you define this?

Comment: that means that i have a set of content, for example 10 lessons, and per week is only one lesson available. Also this works per user, so its one week from the registration of the user

Comment: You are going to have to define what you are trying to accomplish much more closely than that. Wordpress may have a plugin for this, but Wordpress is much simpler. In Drupal there are many ways to do this. Is this content published elsewhere? Is it only supposed to be available to certain user roles? The rules module can allow you to publish certain types of content to certain roles. But real answer would depend on who you are trying to publish this material to and under what circumstances other than "once a week".

Comment: i edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in fact [develop your own module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) to do the above - for example, set a value attached to each user account of number of 'drips' left, which is then decremented by each pageview/similar, and then the total is refreshed at the start of the next billing period, for example by using a scheduled task implemented via the cron system.

Comment: so there is no module for that allready?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of ...